# \thispagestyle{plain} doesn't work

Tags: header-footer, numbering, emptypage

I am trying to delete the header of 5 pages by adding the

> \thispagestyle{plain}

which theoretically allows me to only have the page numbering which is exactly what I want. However, `\thispagestyle{plain}` works exactly like `\thispagestyle{empty}`. It gives me a page with no headers or numbering. If I remove it completely it gives me a header and numbering. I only need the numbering

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\begin{center}
\section*{STATUTORYD ECLARATION}
\end{center}
hereby declare that I have authored this thesis 
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \begin{center}
\section*{Abstract}
    \end{center}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \cleardoublepage
    \begin{center}
\section*{Acknowledgments}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \cleardoublepage
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
\section*{Abbreviations}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoftables
    \newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}    
\section{Introduction} % (fold)
\label{sec:introduction}
```

The packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
% package for bibliography
\usepackage{cite}
% package for header
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{comment}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\ohead[]{\today}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.4pt:head}
```

Comment: One experiment would be to use \pagestyle{plain} and \pagestyle{headings} to turn it on and off again.  But I suspect this is KOMA related.

Comment: I added KOMA lately .. I guess it's something else .. I have zero knowledge so mabe I am mistaken

Comment: Definitely something KOMA-related.  This is because to make the example truly minimal I had to remove lots of the packages you load.  When I removed `scrlayer-scrpage`, it worked as expected.  So I'd look through the documentation there and see what it can teach you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional argument of `\cfoot` sets the content for page style `plain`. Use either

```
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

or its short version

```
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
```

to get the page number on plain pages too.

Comment: Thank you so much